# Update TableView from Asynchronous Data in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift

I'm currently working on an iOS Application and I recently came across the issue that I was downloading and parsing data synchronously and as a result making the app completely unresponsive.

I've updated my code to download my data and parse it asynchronously however I'm now hitting another issue.

I've been trying to split my code up and follow the MVC pattern. I have my TableViewController as the delegate and DataSource of the TableView. I have another class that is managing downloading+parsing my data.

My issue is, once the data is parsed - how do I update the TableView since it's all being done asynchronously.

**TableViewController**

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
println(searchBar.text)

searchBar.resignFirstResponder() //Hide the keyboard

let result = ShowsDataParser.newSearchShows(searchBar.text) //Get search result based on input
searchResults = result.results
maxPages = result.maxPages
currentPage = 1
self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I've implemented all required methods(e.g cellForRowAtIndexPath) within this class too.

**ShowsDataParser**

```
class func newSearchShows(input: String, page:Int = 1) -> (results:[Show], maxPages: Int)
{
let searchUrl = "/search/tv" //Search URL
var searchResults = [Show]()
var totalPages = 1

let posterSize = "w92"

if let escapedSearch = escapeString(input) {
    var search = apiLocation + searchUrl + "?query=" + escapedSearch + "&api_key=" + APIKey + "&page=\(page)"

    if let url = NSURL(string: search)
    {
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler:{data,response,error -> Void in
            if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSDictionary
            {
                var name: String
                var id: Int
                var status: String
                var overview = "meow"
                if let results = json["results"] as? NSArray
                {
                    for result in results
                    {
                        id = result["id"] as! Int
                        name = result["original_name"] as! String
                        //overview = result["overview"] as! String
                        status = ""
                        var newShow = Show(showId: id, showName: name, showDesc: overview, showStatus: status)
                        if let date = result["first_air_date"] as? String
                        {
                            newShow.firstAired = self.formatDate(date)
                        }
                        if let poster = result["poster_path"] as? String
                        {
                            if let baseUrl = AppDelegate.config?.baseUrl
                            {
                                if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: baseUrl + posterSize + poster)!)
                                {
                                    //newShow.posterImage = UIImage(data: data)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        searchResults.append(newShow)
                    }
                }
                if let pages = json["total_pages"] as? Int
                {
                    totalPages = pages
                }
            }

        })
    }

}

return (results: searchResults, maxPages: totalPages)
}
```

As you can see, the above class gets and parses the data from the specified url. I'm simply unsure of how to update the tableview after this is done. Calling upon `self.tableView.reloadData()` within `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` isn't working.

Comment: Don't trigger the reload until you have your data. (in the callback block from your networking)

Comment: Update the data model with the new data and then call `reloadData` on the main thread.

Comment: @Logan How would I go about knowing that I've got the data?

Comment: `searchResults.append(newShow)` implies you've got a new show.  Once you're done iterating through `results`, your data should be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

place the reloadData() call after the if statement

```
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSDictionary
{ 

.... more code 

    if let pages = json["total_pages"] as? Int
    {
        totalPages = pages
    }
}
self.myTableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: The issue is that the ShowDataParser class is not the TableView DataSource. I'm simply calling the method from the TableViewController. As a result, it cannot access the tableView. This is why I was returning the result from parsing it and such.

Comment: then you need a delegate and protocol , make a protocol in the file that has newSearchShows and instead of self.myTableView.reloadData() , in that line call a protocol method (you can send the totalPages as the argument). For this protocol, have the table view controller as the delegate.  That way, TableViewController knows that the request is done in  ShowDataParser . Let me know if this helps!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense actually. Thanks I'll give it a go!